# Error running rails s [ Sass::SyntaxError - Invalid CSS after "...ass}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";": ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to figure out this error for quite some time now and have not been successful. I am working on upgrading a legacy application to the most recent version of ruby and rails. At the moment I am looking to get the application running as is with ruby 2.2.0 | rails 4.2.5. I have not been able to locate the error within the codebase.

When I run `rails s` the application starts up and navigate to localhost:3000 the first thing I see is this error below.

**Current Error**

```
Sass::SyntaxError - Invalid CSS after "...ass}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";":
```

Indicated error exist here line 6: `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml`

Line 6:  `= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true`

**Running Rails s**

```
user@user-2 effort-forecaster % rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma 2.15.3 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-01 14:20:58 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered welcome/index.html.haml within layouts/application (3.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 871ms (ActiveRecord: 16.6ms)

Sass::SyntaxError - Invalid CSS after "...ass}: #{$value}": expected "{", was ";":
```

**application.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title EffortForecast
    = javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'layouts/login_modal'
    %section
      = render 'layouts/header'
    = content_for :subnav

    %section.container-fluid
      .flash-messages= render 'layouts/flash_messages'
      = yield
```

**application.css**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require jasny-bootstrap
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require datatables
 *= require datatables-fixedcolumns
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

I tried searching each par of the error in my code to see if it pops up anywhere in the application, but that was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked in your `application.css` file?

Comment: I have add the `application.css` file above.

Comment: The error indicates that one of your scss files has a syntax error. SASS is the tool that will convert SCSS into regular CSS. One of the things it allows is "interpolation" (so you can use and define variables), and there seems to be a syntax error in one of these cases. Does that help?

Comment: I understand there is an error. I simply can not seem to find it anyway within the codebase. I tried search every part of the error message. Unfortunately, I have come up empty.

Comment: Within that `application.css` file there are a number of `require` directives, to include CSS. You'll need to check those files for errors. I suspect one of the files in your `app/assets/stylesheets` has an invalid token somewhere.